# How to invoke custom tooltip on mouse left click in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I have a list view in which one column only show images. I want to show tool tip on images when user explicitly mouse left click on image. I do not want to show tool tip when user mouse hovers on any image.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) instead of a tooltip on which you set `Popup.IsOpen` to `true` upon click. Might need to adjust placement settings, also `Popup.StaysOpen` should probably be set to `false`.

Edit: As seen in the duplicate question the Tooltip pretty much has the same functionality. Just need to handle it explicitly.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Name="image" MaxHeight="48" Source="{Binding ImgUri}" ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference image}"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ToolTip.IsOpen">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0001" Value="True"/>
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
        <Image.Resources>
            <ToolTip x:Key="tip" StaysOpen="False">
                <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference image}, Path=Source}"/>
            </ToolTip>
        </Image.Resources>
        <Image.ToolTip>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="tip"/>
        </Image.ToolTip>
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

Note that the toolip auto-open functionality has been disabled via `ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"`

(*The above example shows the image that has been clicked in the popup, without the size restrictions*)

Comment: Thanks for the reply H.B. I want when user that tooltip will stay open when user has focus on the tooltip ( when user mouse hovers on tooltip ) and as soon as user click any where the tool tip will close after 2 secs..